# XML catalog in Eclipse WTP: How do you reference a standalone XML schema

Tags: xml, eclipse, xmlcatalog

I have an XML schema document (provided by a company I deal with) to validate a certain XML file that is required for their system.

Lets say the first couple of lines of the schema look like this (I have modified the URIs to protect the guilty!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/manifest-plugin"
xmlns="http://www.example.com/manifest-plugin">
```

The URI in the XSD is not valid in the unmodified original i.e. you cannot go there to get a copy of this XSD file. I have no idea why they haven't published it at the URL defined in the XSD, but they haven't.

I have a local copy of the XSD which I would like to use to validate the XML file I create using the features of Eclipse's XML catalog. Obviously, as the URI is invalid there is no point to let the system try to retrieve the XSD from the web.

Let's say the local XSD file lives on my local drive here:

```
C:\xml_schemas\manifest-plugin.xsd
```

And the opening two lines of the XML file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
```

Could anyone give an example of how to do this?

Specifically:

1. What values do I set in the XML catalog dialog boxes in Eclipse, based on the values I have provided above?
2. What do I put into the XML file to get it to validate against the local XSD, without confusing other systems which my read my XML file down the line?

I have found this page on the Eclipse wiki, but I personally don't find the instructions very clear:-

[Using the XML catalog in Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog)

I have tried setting the XML catalog parameters thus:

- Location : C:\xml_schemas\manifest-plugin.xsd
- Key type : Namespace name
- Key : http://www.example.com/manifest-plugin

Then adding

```
<manifest xmlns:targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/manifest-plugin">
```

to the XML file, but it doesn't seem to work.

By the way, if your version of Eclipse doesn't have the XML catalog, you probably haven't got the "web tools platform (WTP)" features installed. They come with the Java EE version of Eclipse, but can be installed separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can specify a local schema location which will take precedence over the remote location of the XML Schema file.

As such, if you put your XSD file in the directory where your XML files are, the header of your manifest.xml file should be:

```
<manifest xmlns="http://my.super.xsd.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com manifest.xsd">
```

I tested under Eclipse, it works (you can even click on the XSD link).
Now, that works if both your XSD and XML files are in the same directory.

If you want to have your XSD in a separate local location, you have to use the [`file`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) protocol. Given your example, your XML file would look like so:

```
<manifest xmlns="http://my.super.xsd.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com file:///C|/xml_schemas/manifest-plugin.xsd"">
```

This example also works under Eclipse, although when clicking on the XSD, it opens the web browser (at least for me).

Comment: Ok... thanks for the response, but I have now clarified my question, as I don't think you got what exactly I was asking.

Comment: I changed my answer, I think that this time it should work for you. Although, it really has nothing to do with the XML catalog from Eclipse.

Comment: One more question: The final output of this project is a WAR file. Would you recommend including the XSD in this file by dropping it in the same directory as the XML file, and changing the path to it to a relative one, as per your top example? Or will it be fine to keep my XSD on my local drive, but export an XML file that refers to a local file on my machine in its xsi:schemaLocation?

Comment: @Geeb I'll recommend you to include the XSD file in the same directory as the XML file and change to a relative path. If you do runtime XSD validation it will work on every machine, not just yours. Moreover, if your schema evolves (suppose you need to add a few things in it for another project), your previous WAR would still be fine because the XML would relate to its own version of the XSD file.

Comment: Your technique appears to work **completely independently of the XML catalog!** I have deleted all references to the XSD in the catalog and Eclipse still sees the XML as valid, now the XSD is in the same directory. _Makes you wonder what the point of the catalog is?_

Comment: @Geeb Well the *schemaLocation* has nothing to do with the XML Catalog in Eclipse. The XML Catalog is only useful when validating your XML files with Eclipse because it redirects the remote location to the location found in the catalog. It may be useful for enterprise developers for example, when the catalog and all useful schemas have been copied to a network location. Using this catalog developers have no need to connect to the remote address each time the document is validated, and they also don't need their own copy.

Comment: This answer is useful, but it doesn’t answer the question. How do you do the same with the XML catalog? Assume XML is sent to a different system, then you couldn’t assume that the XSD is locally available at the recipient. So you would not write a schemaLocation into the document. Still you might want to look at and validate the sent XML documents. How would you do that in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

It should be pretty straight forward.  From the XML Catalog preferences page click "Add" to get the "Add XML Catalog Element" dialog.  There you want to add a Catalog Entry with the following attributes:

- Location: <path-to-local-xsd>
- Key Type: Namespace Name
- Key: http://www.example.com/manifest-plugin

The local XSD can either be in your workspace (using Eclipse path variables) or on the file system external to the workspace.  After adding the entry Eclipse should be able to validate XML documents in the workspace.

Note that the XML Catalog doesn't have anything to do with your applications runtime validation of XML documents.

Update: The XML file should then contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns="http://www.example.com/manifest-plugin">
...
```

In Eclipse 3.6 or 3.7 you should see a dialog like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't seem to have the option of selecting a Public ID as the keytype?! I only get two options: "Schema Location" or "Namespace name" ...

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the dialog as it appears in 3.6 and 3.7 (the only versions I have conveniently available).  What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Use "Namespace Name" as key type and your namespace as key. Make sure your XML declares the namespace in the root element: <manifest xmlns="...">...</manifest>

Comment: @Chris Thanks - I should have actually tried adding an entry since it has been a while since I've actually done it.  I just tried it and now see that the Key Type choices change depending on whether you select a DTD or XML Schema.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if schemaloaction is not specified in the xml, you should be able to use XML catelog in Eclipse to override the schema location.